# How to determine how much is paid to OASDI?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

Same state. Same status.

I recently switched jobs ($130k to $200k) and I noticed a huge amount goes to OASDI but before I didn't pay any.

My overall tax deduction went from 24% to 36%.

I am not-resident on a visa if that matters.

I checked [this](https://www.fool.com/taxes/2017/04/08/what-oasdi-tax-is-and-why-you-should-care.aspx) website, but it seems that in any case I would had to pay it before anyway ($130k).

Comment: [Here](https://www.ssa.gov/policy/docs/quickfacts/prog_highlights/index.html) are some numbers from ssa.gov. They look like percentages, but I'm not familiar with it, so I'll just leave you to add the relevant numbers to your question as part of your research for the question. You can use the [edit] link to add information to your question.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not-resident on a visa if that matters.

This is likely the reason.  There are a number of groups that can be exempt from paying OASDI, and nonresidents are one of them.  It will depend on the specific visa, and the specific employer; you can get the full details at [Aliens Employed in the U.S. – Social Security Taxes](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/aliens-employed-in-the-us-social-security-taxes)

If this is the case, it is possible it is either a misclassification by your new employer, or that the new employer no longer falls under the exemption requirements.

If youare *not* exempt, then the details are described at [OASDI and SSI Program Rates & Limits, 2018](https://www.ssa.gov/policy/docs/quickfacts/prog_highlights/RatesLimits2018.html); for a W2 employee, it would be 7.65% for the first $128,400 (SSI and Medicare); 1.45% on $128,401-$200,000 (Medicare), and 2.35% thereafter (Medicare at the high-earner's rate). For a 1099 contractor, who is paying both the employer and employee portions, it would be 15.3% on the first $128,400, 2.9% for $128,401-$200,000, and 3.8% thereafter (all rates being doubled except the 0.9% high-earner's addition applied after $200,000).